# Higher accuracy on placing bounding spheres

Tags: c#, xna

Im trying to add bounding spheres to models for collision detection. The problem is that the models bottom are always on same level with the  center of the sphere. Is there a way to find the middle of the model(based on Y axis) so that i can have that as center of the sphere ? Think that would solve my problem . Thanks in advance.

```
protected BoundingSphere CalculateBoundingSphere()
        {
            BoundingSphere mergedSphere = new BoundingSphere();
            BoundingSphere[] boundingSpheres;
            int index = 0;
            int meshCount = Model.Meshes.Count;

            boundingSpheres = new BoundingSphere[meshCount];
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
            {
                boundingSpheres[index++] = mesh.BoundingSphere;
            }

            mergedSphere = boundingSpheres[0];
            if ((Model.Meshes.Count) > 1)
            {
                index = 1;
                do
                {
                    mergedSphere = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(mergedSphere,
                        boundingSpheres[index]);
                    index++;
                } while (index < Model.Meshes.Count);
            }

            return mergedSphere;
        }
```

Comment: Also by changing mergedSphere.Center.Y for some reason i dont get any different placement.

Comment: When a sphere is used as model the boundingsphere is placed correctly. The problem is with other shapes like cubes . The bottom of the cube is on the center of the sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when folks have problems with boundingSphere location, they are not taking bone transforms into account.

Since you are merging spheres, it implies you have multiple ModelMesh objects... each of which has its own ModelBone object which has a transform matrix.

When the content processor creates a bounding sphere from the vertices of a mesh, it does not take into account any bone transforms that may be affecting the final location of the mesh. So it is important to manually translate the mesh's BoundingSphere.Center by the bone transform's Translation property to set the correct location for the Boundingsphere.

For instance:

```
Matrix[] meshTransforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(meshTransforms);

//then in the foreach loop
int tempIndex = Index++;
boundingSpheres[tempIndex] = mesh.BoundingSphere;
boundingSpheres[tempIndex].Center += meshTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index].Translation;
```